# How to find the chrome browser version using terminal in MAC?

Tags: bash, macos, google-chrome, terminal

Tried the below; but nothing seems to work

```
google-chrome --version

google-chrome-stable --version

chrome --version
```

[image]

**Build: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)**[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question says "in Linux/Mac".  Looking at the issue you have it looks like you might be using a mac, in which case the `google-chome` binary will be hidden away in the Applications folder.  On my mac, this works:

```
$ /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version                                                                            
Google Chrome 59.0.3071.104
```

If you're not using a mac, it could well be because the path to your `google-chome` binary isn't in your `$PATH` variable, so I'd either specify the complete path, or add the right path to `$PATH`.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried in my terminal. It's working. Please check yours. Please make sure that you have installed google chrome, not chromium.

**Update for Mac:** 
Your Mac is not allowing google-chrome as an environment variable. So, you can't access from terminal or CLI. You may use simple hack,

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version
```

*Note:* The command will be like that. Use according to your machine.

```
google-chrome --version
```

[image]

Comment: it failed to work in couple of my machines; i use MAC.. hope u notice the screenshot in the question

Comment: Is that chrome or chromium?

Comment: It's chrome browser

Comment: Ok. sounds great. let me check in Mac.I was using Linux in screenshot

Comment: Thanks @ashraful